# How do I output a simple count (int) from a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to obtain the distinct count of a column in my data table.

I have the following so far

```
    public int DocumentsProcessed()
    {

        var query = from data in this._data
                    let docID = data.Field<string>("Document ID")
                    select new
                    {
                        docID
                    };

        var query2 = from d in query
                     select d.docID.Distinct().Count();

        var result = query2;

        return result;
    }
```

where this._data is

```
private IEnumerable<DataRow> _data;
```

But the result is an IEnumerable.  I'm looking for just a single integer as an answer.

**EDIT**: I tried grouping the data first by Document ID column and then counting the groups, but it gave me the wrong number - for example I have 16 rows where all the Document ID are the same, so the Distinct count should be **1** but I was getting **16**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your example for **every row** you're doing a select distinct.  I believe what you want is:

```
var query = from data in this._data
            let docID = data.Field<string>("Document ID")
            select new
            {
                docID
            };

var distinctCount = query.Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that data is DataTable object so try it in this manner

```
int count = _data.
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Document ID"))
.Distinct()
.Count();
```